# Submonoid of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ generated by two matrices.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I'm trying to figure out which kind of matrices can be written as $A^{k_{1}}B^{k_{2}}...A^{k_{n}}B^{k_{n}}$ where

A=$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and B=$\begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

I did it for $C=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and got that any word on $\{C,D\}$ appears as $\begin{pmatrix} a&2b\\2c&d\end{pmatrix}$with $a$ and $d$ odd and obviously $2b$ and $2c$ even. I can show this for $\{C,D\}$, but can't find an expression for $B^{k}$ so I can't go on and look for something similar.

Comment: But $C^3=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, so the upper right-hand corner is not always even in your second example (which also can be seen just by considering the word $C$ itself). It is well-known that $C$ and $D$ generate $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for every prime $p$.

Comment: Noting that $A^{-1}B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, you will not be able to describe the monoid generated by $A$ and $B$ using congruence conditions for this reason. (Unless that congruence condition is that anything that happens in $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ can happen modulo $p$ in the monoid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding $B^k$:

$B$ is Hermitian and thus diagonalizable.  [See this for details](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-diagonalization-calculator/diagonalize%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D2%261%5C%5C%201%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D).  So, we have that:

$$B = \overbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} & \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \\ 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}^{P}
\overbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}}^{D}
\overbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}
\end{pmatrix}}^{P^{-1}}
$$
So, we can write $B = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal.  It follows that $B^k = PD^kP^{-1}$, which you should be able to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $A^{-2}BA^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ so the subgroup generated by $A,B$ is $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Now for the monoid generated by $A,B$, I don't know.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not clear enough: I can do just products of A and B, not their inverses. I knew A and B generate the group SL(2,Z)

Comment: @Roger it is not a group then, only a monoid (the title was "subgroup generated by")

Comment: yeah my bad, should have said monoid

Comment: @Roger and the monoid generated by $A^{-1},B$ should be simpler since $C = A^{-2}BA^{-1}$ has order $2$ : $C^2 = I$

Comment: I'm studying Cayley hash functions. There's a scheme which uses these matrices as generators for the Cayley graph. The hash works well if the monoid generated by $A$ and $B$ is "small" cause a forger can't find collisions

Comment: @Roger you can try to represent your monoid  in [the modular group tilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane) of the upper half-plane, you can represent $A$ as "move right" and $B$ as "move left two times, symmetrize with respect to $z = i$, and move left"

Comment: I barely know the modular group, I'm trying to understand what you suggest, but I'm stuck. Can't see how to describe the monoid